How to Customize PDF Report Footer in Odoo 17 to Show 'PTO' Text Only on Non-Final Pages?
I am using Odoo 17 and have a PDF report in Odoo where I custom-created the footer to include the page number and 'PTO' text. The footer currently appears on all pages, but I want the 'PTO' text to appear only on non-final pages. Additionally, if the PDF report consists of only one page, the 'PTO' text should not be shown
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6 text-left" style="font-size:12px">

              <div class="text-muted">Page: <span class="page"/> of <span class="topage"/><br/>
                <span class="not-last-page">PTO</span>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>

I want the 'PTO' text to appear only on non-final pages. Additionally, if the PDF report consists of only one page, the 'PTO' text should not be shown
